# appropriate approximation for the lower bound of minimum of two independent random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I have a question about lower bound approximation of two independent RVs; if we have this formula;

$ x = (ab/a+b+1) $

Where a and b are two independent RVs.
So that we can find the equivalent PDF of the above formula an approximation has been adopted as:

$ x_{app} = (ab/a+b) $

from which we can get the upper bound:

$ x_{ub} = min(a,b) $

Also I saw the lower bound for the above formula written as:

$ x_{lb} = 0.5 min(a,b) $

my question is that; what is the reason behind chosing 0.5 for the lower bound?

Comment: Do you mean $ab/(a+b+1)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_{app}(a,b) = \dfrac{ab}{a+b}$ and $a,b > 0$.  If $a \le b$ (so $\min(a,b) = a$)) then
$$ \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{b}{b+b} \le \dfrac{b}{a+b} \le 1$$
so
$$ \dfrac{\min(a,b)}{2} \le x_{app}(a,b) \le \min(a,b)$$
The upper bound also holds for $x = \dfrac{ab}{a+b+1}$, but not the lower bound.
But if $a$ and $b$ are large compared to $1$, the difference may not be significant.

Comment: I think the lower bound occure when a=b, because for that case `min(a,b)=b` then the formula will be `b/2`

Comment: could you tell me how to find the equivalent PDF of 
$ x_{lb} = 0.5 min(a,b) $
in the case of both RV are exponentialy distributed.
Thanks

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are independent exponential random variables with rates rate parameters $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_b$, then $\min(a,b)$ has an exponential distribution with rate parameter $\lambda_a + \lambda_b$.